# Jacobian of n linearly independent forms in n variables

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero and let $f_1, \ldots, f_n \in k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]_d$ be linearly independent forms of degree $d$ in $n$ variables.

Is there a nice algebraic argument for proving that the determinant of the Jacobian matrix $(\frac{\partial{f_i}}{\partial x_j})_{1\leq i,j \leq n}$ is not identically zero (if that statement is correct)?

Comment: $f_i$  must be  functionally independed

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "functionally independent". Since $k$ has infinitely many elements the forms $f_1, \ldots, f_n$ are linearly independent as functions from $k^n$ to $k$. Could you specify that?

Comment: It  means  that there is no any function  $F[y_1,y_2,\ldots, y_n]$   such that  holds  $F[f_1,f_2,\ldots, f_n] \neq 0.$

Comment: I see (probably $F \neq 0$). Is functional independence equivalent to the statement in the question?

Comment: yes, that are equivalent statements

Comment: @Leox: no they are not.

Comment: yes, I see  now....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is incorrect as attested by the case $n=3, d=2$ and  the linearly independent polynomials  $$f_1=x_1^2,\quad f_2=x_1x_2,\quad f_3=x_2^2 $$ 
The jacobian determinant is identically zero.
Indeed its third column is zero, because the $f_i$'s do not not depend on $x_3$.

Answer (score 1):

$f_i$ must be functionally independent.

Comment: Dear Leox:  could you explain what you mean, given that the statement  in the question is false.

Comment: I mean a general situation  not the  statement.